# How to define multiplication in covering group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected topological group and let $p:\tilde{G}\to G$ be a **universal covering** of $G$. Then $\tilde{G}$ is also a topological group and $p$ is a continuous homomorphism.

My question is: How do we define multiplication in $\tilde{G}$? We can define a map $$p\times p:\tilde{G}\times \tilde{G} \to G, \quad (x,x)\mapsto (p(x),p(x))$$

and try to lift it to a map $\tilde{G} \times \tilde{G} \to \tilde{G}$. Such a lift exists iff $(p\times p)_{*} \pi_1(\tilde{G}\times \tilde{G}) \subset p_*\pi_1(H)$.

Is this condition satisfied? If so, how do we verify that this actually gives us a group structure?

Comment: Your question lacks mention of base points.  Choose the base point in $G$ for $\tilde{G}$ to be the identity $e$, and use $(e,e)$ and $e$ as base points upstairs, to get the lift you require.  Note that a universal cover is simply connected, so the condition is easily satisfied. Note also that the connected assumption is crucial.

Comment: where do we need to connected assumption?

Comment: Connectivity of $G$ is used as follows: if $G$ is connected, then we have a clear choice of base points in $G$ and $\tilde{G}$, using $e$. If $G$ is not connected, we do not know how to choose base points outside of the identity component. It is easy to forget that **the** fundamental group and **the** universal cover are defined not for a space but for a space with base point. My joint paper ``Covering groups of non-connected topological  groups revisited'',  _Math. Proc. Camb. Phil.Soc_,  115 (1994) 97-110. deals with the general  question.